# Mudar valor de variável no Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

## O Problema

Tenho a variável `flagExistenciaArquivo`, e preciso que ela seja atualizada caso o arquivo exista ou não. Eu chamo a função `verificaExistenciaArquivo` dentro de outra função, colocando como parâmetro a *pasta* desse arquivo e *nome do arquivo*. Caso o arquivo seja achado, ele retorna `true`, caso contrário,  `false`. Preciso que ao entrar no `success` ou `error` do Ajax, eu consiga mudar o valor da variável de flag.

## Meu Código

```
var flagExistenciaArquivo = true;

function verificaExistenciaArquivo(pasta, nomeArquivo) {
    var baseUrl = 'http://' + $(location).attr('hostname') + '/monitoramento-mobile/assets/fotos/';

    if(pasta == 'assinaturas_entrevista') {
        arquivo = baseUrl + 'assinaturas_entrevista/' + nomeArquivo;
    }else if (pasta == null) {
        arquivo = baseUrl + nomeArquivo;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: arquivo,
        type:'HEAD',
        success: function()
        {
            //mudar valor da variável para true
        },
        error: function()
        {
            //mudar valor da variável para false
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Não é só usar `flagExistenciaArquivo = true;` ou `flagExistenciaArquivo = false;` ?

Comment: Na verdade, a request feita com sucesso vai sempre cair no `success`, então você tem que verificar lá pegando o parâmetro de retorno do callback, e.g. `success(data)`, sendo que `data` deve ser seu retorno booleano.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Você teria um código de exemplo para eu entender melhor como ficaria o callback ?

Comment: O @DiegoSouza explicou bem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

como o método AJAX é assicrono, o retorno da função `verificaExistenciaArquivo` vai ocorrer antes do retorno do AJAX.

Você até pode setar a propriedade `async: false` do `$.ajax`, mas isto não é recomendado, o ideal é passar uma função de `callback` para `verificaExistenciaArquivo`.

```
function verificaExistenciaArquivo(pasta, nomeArquivo, callback) {
    var baseUrl = 'http://' + $(location).attr('hostname') + '/monitoramento-mobile/assets/fotos/';

    if(pasta == 'assinaturas_entrevista') {
        arquivo = baseUrl + 'assinaturas_entrevista/' + nomeArquivo;
    }else if (pasta == null) {
        arquivo = baseUrl + nomeArquivo;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: arquivo,
        type:'HEAD',
        success: function()
        {
            callback(true);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
}

verificaExistenciaArquivo("nomeDaPasta", "nomeDoArquivo", function (existe) {
    console.log(existe ? "Arquivo Existe" : "Arquivo não existe");
});
```

Neste caso tambem não é interresante ter uma variavel global para informar a existencia do arquivo, ou você elimina ela como no exemplo acima, ou declare ela dentro de uma closure.

Um segundo problema é que você está baixando todo o arquivo apenas para saber se ele existe, o ideal seria abortar a requisição assim que o servidor responder com o `readyState: 2 (request recebido)`

```js
var uploadFile = document.getElementById("uploadFile");
var linkURL = document.getElementById("linkURL");

var createLink = document.getElementById("createLink");
var destroyLink = document.getElementById("destroyLink");
var linkExists = document.getElementById("linkExists");

// criar um link em memoria para o arquivo selecionado.
createLink.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (uploadFile.files.length > 0) {
    linkURL.value = URL.createObjectURL(uploadFile.files[0]);
  }
});

// destruir o link em memoria para o arquivo selecionado
destroyLink.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (linkURL.value) {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(linkURL.value);
  }
});

// verificar se o link em memoria existe
linkExists.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  if (linkURL.value) {
    verificaExistenciaArquivo(linkURL.value, function (exists) {
      // exists pode assumir 3 valores:
      // true: arquivo encontrado
      // false: arquivo não encontrado
      // undefined: erro na requisição
      console.log(exists);
    });
  }
});

// verificar se existe algum arquivo no link em memoria.
var verificaExistenciaArquivo = function (url, callback) {
  var done = false;
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest ();  
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    //readyState 0 a 4: 
    //0: request não enviado
    //1: conexão estabelecida
    //2: request recebido
    //3: processando request
    //4: resposta pronta     
    var response = { readyState: xmlHttp.readyState, status: xmlHttp.status };
    if (!done) {     
      switch (response.readyState)
      {
        // 0 antes do 2 - caso o request seja abortado antes da resposta do servidor (timeout).
        case 0: 
          callback(undefined); 
          break;
        //conexão com o servidor bem sucessida, e o mesmo já respondeu com um status.
        case 2:
          done = true;
          xmlHttp.abort();
          switch (response.status)
          {
            case 200: callback(true); break;
            case 404: callback(false); break;
            default: callback(undefined); break;
          }
          break;
        // 4 antes do 1 - Conexão recusada (possivelmente CORS bloqueado)
        case 4: 
          callback(undefined); 
          break;
      }
    }    
  }

  xmlHttp.open("GET", url);
  xmlHttp.send();
}
```

```css
#linkURL {
    width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input id="uploadFile" type="file" />
<div>
    <input id="createLink" type="button" value="Criar Link" />
    <input id="destroyLink" type="button" value="Destruir Link" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        Link Criado:
        <input id="linkURL" type="text" disabled />
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="linkExists" type="button" value="Verificar Link" />
</div>
```

Comment: Só vai cair no callback de erro se der erro na request, caso contrário vai cair no success com o retorno no primeiro parâmetro.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Toby

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown,  Don't Vote Me Down

Comment: Pelo o que entendi ele esta pedindo um arquivo ao servidor e não acessando uma API para perguntar se um determinado arquivo existe ou não, então se o arquivo existe ele vai retornar um codigo 200 (sucess), se não existir codigo 404 (error), claro que outras situações de erro podem criar um falso positivo.

Comment: Assim ele mostra na linha que do error: "callback is not definied".

Comment: note que adicionei mais um argumento na função `verificaExistenciaArquivo`, no caso o `callback`

Comment: Ah sim, verdade, não tinha mudada a url. Coloquei acima do if o arquivo = null, mas pelo visto ele sempre esta caindo no success. E o console.log não está sendo mostrado, apesar do Chrome não indicar erro no JS.

Comment: vou colocar um exemplo usando XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @AllanRamos, dá uma olhada agora.

Answer (score 2):

Era mais fácil você verificar a existência do arquivo em uma página server-side. Provavelmente PHP você esteja utilizando.

### PHP

```
<?php
    $file = $_POST['file'];
    $caminho = 'dir/';
    if(file_exists($caminho.$file))
       $boo = "true";
    else
       $boo = "false";

    return $boo;
?>
```

E no JS você pega o retorno da página PHP e apenas trata no `callback` da função `success`.

### JS

```
var flagExistenciaArquivo = true;

function verificaExistenciaArquivo(pasta, nomeArquivo) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'pagina.php',
        data: { file: nomeArquivo },
        type:'POST',
        async: false,
        success: function(result){
            if(!result)
               flagExistenciaArquivo = false;
        },
    });
    return flagExistenciaArquivo;
}
```

Comment: Blz, concordo, mas como o  @DontVoteMeDown disse, eu teria que fazer um callback para mudar o estado dessa variável, correto ?

Comment: Exatamente. Editei meu post.